# Change map style of mapbox-gl-cordova-offline map in Cordova app

Tags: cordova, offline, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mbtiles

I have created an app with Cordova, that has an offline map with vector tiles. I used [mapbox-gl-cordova-offline](https://github.com/oscarfonts/mapbox-gl-cordova-offline) for offline maps.

At the moment, the mbtiles files for the offline map is integrated in the APK and the offline map works fine. But now I want to add the possibility to switch between offline and online maps. The switch from the integrated offline map to an online map works by using setStyle() on the map. But when I try to set the style back to the offline map, I get the following error:

> Error: sources.openmaptiles.type: expected one of [vector, raster, raster-dem, geojson, video, image], "mbtiles" found

So the problem here is, that inside my style-offline.json there is "mbtiles" for data source like  [described in readme of mapbox-gl-cordova-offline](https://github.com/oscarfonts/mapbox-gl-cordova-offline#offline-data-sources-mbtiles).

As a final result I want to be able to download mbtiles from a server and save them locally in app folder (this also works fine). I just can't get it working to load the loaded mbtiles for the map...

Anyone any help or hints for me?

---

**Update:**

I'm still struggling with this... I wrote a function, that downloads and unzips a zip file to *cordova.file.dataDirectory*. The zip file contains everything that's needed for the offline map (the same structure as the integrated offline map files).

Instead of using setStyle(), I just create a new offline map with changed options. This works fine, if the files are integrated in the app. And then I try to create a new offline map with the loaded files like this:

```
mapboxgl.OfflineMap({
  style: cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'map/styles/osm-bright/style-offline.json',
  container: 'map'
}).then(function(map) {
  mapCallback(map);
});
```

All I get are `FileError {code: 1}`... But I don't see which file is not found (but I believe they are the missing tiles from mbtiles files).

But I don't understand why the files are not found. I can imagine that it's maybe because of CORS or something within the plugins code. But I can't find anything yet. And wouldn't there be a console error when it's some CORS problem instead of FileErrors?